# Using stencil to mask image in kv

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Been looking through the documentation but can't find out how to properly mask an image in kv. This is my kv code:

```
<MyImage@AsyncImage>:
    source: 'http://webserver/120x100.png'
    canvas.before:
        StencilPush
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: 120,100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to to call StencilUse to use the stencil layer. Also remember to unuse and pop:

```
<MyImage@AsyncImage>:
    source: 'http://webserver/120x100.png'
    canvas.before:
        StencilPush
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: 120,100
        StencilUse
    canvas.after:
        StencilUnUse
        StencilPop
```

Comment: The image is being dynamically generated, and I have no control over the source. Just need it to have rounded corners, but I don't think there's a way of doing this just with the Image in kv?

Comment: Ah, you are doing this for the rounded corners! Sorry, yes, then this seems like "the best solution".

Comment: Well you could probably also download the file and modify it before showing it (e.g. modify it with PIL or pillow or whatever) but that's probably more trouble than it's worth.